# Make each class unique

Tags: html, css

I am mainting a website there consist of almost 120.000 pages. I am working on a new layout for the mainpage, and therefore I need to make each class unique so the rest of the website is not affected.

If i fx want to make an `a` tag unique, how am I doing that correctly? Is it fx `<h1 class="foo-a">Hover on me</h1>`, and in the CSS: `foo-a {etc}`?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>CSS Smooth Animation of Element's Text Color</title>
<style type="text/css">
    a {
        margin: 20px;
        -webkit-transition: color 0.5s; /* For Safari 3.0 to 6.0 */
        transition: color 0.5s; /* For modern browsers */
    }
    a:hover {
        color: #ff0000;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><a href="#">Hover on me</a></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you just can making class for the 'a' i think? what you want is all the link has different css style...right?

Comment: what do you mean by "making a tag unique" ?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The classes that I am making now should only affect the main page, and no other page. As I see it I can do that with a prefix?

Comment: @Chocorean, thank you for your comment. I mean if I fx say `a {color: red}`, then all the 120.000 pages will have the color red. If I instead use someting like: sbp-a {color: green}, and use that class only on my mainpage - it is only the mainpage there is using that class.

Comment: Just don't load that stylesheet on pages you don't want the styles.

Comment: You can give classes unique names, however the point of classes are to use them on multiple elements so that those multiple elements will be affected by a single or more CSS rules, which in the end could make your CSS easier to maintain. If you really want unique styling on certain elements, the best approach would be using an `id` with a custom name rather than multiple classes with unique names.

Comment: `id` selectors should not at all be used for styling purposes with very few, well-considered exceptions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i hope this is the answer. So basically you want if there's multiple link in one page, you want making all the link has unique style right?

You can just making class="" for the a, here's the example ...

```css
a {
        margin: 20px;
        -webkit-transition: color 0.5s; /* For Safari 3.0 to 6.0 */
        transition: color 0.5s; /* For modern browsers */
    }
    a:hover {
        color: #ff0000;
    }
    
 a.example01 {color:red;}
 
  a.example02 {color:green;}
  
   a.example03 {font-style:italic;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>CSS Smooth Animation of Element's Text Color</title>
<style type="text/css">
    
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><a class="example01" href="#">Hover on me</a></h1>
    
    <h1><a class="example02" href="#">Hover on me</a></h1>

  <a class="example03" href="#">Hover on me</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is really just as bad of an idea as OP is asking. This willl create loads of totally useless classes with very unsemantic naming. What a maintenance and extension nightmare!

Comment: the OP asking 'each' class, so i'm just making example of unique classing for the <a>. Of course is the bad idea, I also don't want to make classes for all links.

Answer (score 4):

As a probably more practical and doable approach to make any style declarations not affect other pages, just give the body element of the main page an `id` or `class` that no other page has on any element, like `<body id="this-is-the-only-true-main-page">` or `<body class="this-is-the-only-true-main-page">`.

Now to do your main page restylings, simply prefix any selector you use with that class/id. So instead of doing

```
.my-class { color: red; }
```

you do

```
.this-is-the-only-true-main-page .my-class { color: red; }
```

This context selector will make sure it affects only elements with `.my-class` **that have an ancestor element with `.this-is-the-only-true-main-page`**.

Answer (score 0):

Write CSS in a way that one should be able to update visual design of site without touching HTML and write new html component without touching CSS.

If you would have used '**one class one responsibility**' principle, you  might not have to worried about it now.
You might solve the problem of affecting other pages by prefixing class but your CSS will grow eventually witch is not good.
You can move to scoped CSS witch is better solution than creating new classes but for large site it is not maintainable.

Try solution given by @connexo it is more maintainable if using Scss.